# Simply the best... query :)

Tags: mysql, performance

[image: tables]

Current query:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    IFNULL(c.title, b.title) AS title
FROM
    products a
LEFT JOIN translates b ON a.id = b.product_id
AND b.language_id = 1
LEFT JOIN translates c ON a.id = c.product_id
AND c.language_id = 2
```

This is a simplified version of the working query.
What it does: selects all the goods and translating for them, and if there is a translation for language 2 (it does not always exist) - it is more preferred, but if not - then language 1 (translation into that language always is).

Is it possible to improve this query?

Answer (score 3):

Your query should be fine.  I would write it as:

```
SELECT p.id, COALESCE(t1.title, t1.title) AS title
FROM products p LEFT JOIN
     translates t1
     ON p.id = t1.product_id AND t1.language_id = 1 LEFT JOIN
     translates t2
     ON p.id = t2.product_id AND t2.language_id = 2;
```

(Using table aliases that are abbreviations of the table name helps make the query more understandable.)

For performance, you want an index on `translates(product_id, language_id)`.  I can't think of another way to write that query that I would expect to be faster than this version.